# refer to same object

Tags: javascript, object, self

How can I set the locations based on the board below? Thanks

```
let initialState = {
  board: [
    [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1],
    [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1],
    [0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1],
    [-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0],
    [2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1],
    [-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2],
    [2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1]
  ],
  locations: calcLocations(self.board)
};
```

it doesn't recognize self.board...

Comment: use the keyword `this`, not self. But you have to be inside the scope.

Comment: no... that won't work either

Comment: Do you want `locations` to be a value-property or a function-property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a new variable to hold the intermediate result:

```
let board = [ -1, 1, etc ];
let initialState = {
    board: board,
    locations: calcLocations( board )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `this` keyword, and you have to be inside the scope `{}` for it to work.

```
let initialState = {
  board: [
    ...
  ],
  locations: function() {
    return calcLocations(this.board);
  }
};
```

Note that to get the locations becomes a function: `initialState.locations();`

Comment: That makes `locations` a a function-property, not a value-property.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use `this`, but don't want to use a function, you can use a getter. On the 1st call, the getter generates the value, and caches it on `this._locations`. From the now on the getter would return the cached value.

```js
const calcLocations = JSON.stringify;

const initialState = {
  board: [
    [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1],
    [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1],
    [0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1],
    [-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0],
    [2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1],
    [-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2],
    [2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1]
  ],
  get locations() {
    if(!this._locations) this._locations = calcLocations(this.board);
    
    return this._locations; 
  }
};

console.log(initialState.locations);
```